# Autosys command to identify jobs which are ON ICE | ON HOLD

Tags: autosys

under Migration process, we need to identify the commands/box which are kept ON HOLD/ON ICE. We are doing this activity as we need to delete those unused jobs.

Please let me know the Autosys command to list these unused jobs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this manually, then a simple grep/find should work for you, for example:

in Unix:

```
autorep -wj ALL | grep OI

autorep -wj ALL | grep OH
```

or in a Windows agent CMD:

`autorep -wj ALL | find "OI"`    *or OH for on_hold jobs*

However, if you plan to automate this, you can write a simple program that uses the above commands as a base, then parse the output.